# Could we apply text align justify in titanium appcelerator

Tags: alignment, titanium, label, appcelerator, justify

I want to apply justify property to text in titanium Appcelerator. Is there any way to apply it?

Answer (score 1):

[Label](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Label-object) has the attribute "textAlign" but the only supported values are *"left", "center", "right" and the [TEXT_ALIGNMENT_constants](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI-module)*.

**"Justify" is not supported.**

You can also check the following threads for more detail answers :

- [Text Align Justify Titanium ?](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149692/text-align-justify)
- [Jira - Text Align Justify](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-3408)

**Edit :** If you want to use html type formatting on [Labels](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Label-object) you can use following properties :

- For android use [html](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label-property-html) property.
- For ios use [attributedString](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label-property-attributedString) property. More detail for ios formatting [here](http://www.tidev.io/2014/11/13/using-basic-html-in-labels-on-ios-like-android/).